# Bound vs unbound threads in Haskell

Tags: multithreading, haskell, unbound

I am trying to understand exactly how bound threads are implemented in Haskell.

I can instantiate multiple schedulers by passing in the `-N[n]` flag. Are these schedulers executing on individual OS threads?

By using `forkOS` from `Control.Concurrent` I am create a bound thread. Now, the documentation states that the thread will still be scheduled by the Haskell runtime-system, but it will appear as if it was created using `pthread_create` to any foreign functions. How is this actually realized? All foreign calls will be made from the same OS thread so that they can access thread-local state, but is there a chance that multiple bound threads may be pinned to the same OS thread?

I guess I am trying to understand when the *actual* OS threads are created, and how it is implemented that the Haskell threads *appear* to be bound.

Answer (score 1):

> I can instantiate multiple schedulers by passing in the -N[n] flag. Are these schedulers executing on individual OS threads?

Yes.

> All foreign calls will be made from the same OS thread so that they can access thread-local state, but is there a chance that multiple bound threads may be pinned to the same OS thread?

No, but I believe that OS thread may sometimes also be executing unbound Haskell threads. I believe those Haskell threads will be pushed to another scheduler (if there is one) before jumping into a foreign call.